# why/where is this componentDidMount() getting called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In the beginning stages of a project. basically just created a boilerplate react project with that one npx command and now I'm trying to fill it out and make it my own. Right now I'm calling a json response with a fetch call. that json data contains all the apps and their info which will be rendered on the screen. but right now I'm rendering the data more than once. I'm not sure why. or where. any help is appreciated. thanks!

Here's the HomePageComponent.js page

```
export default class HomePageComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super();
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.list)
        this.setState({apps:response.data.list})
        console.log(this.state)
    })
}

render() {
    console.log('render lifecycle')
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter >
                <div className="most-popular-grid">
                    <h3 className="mostpopulartitle">MOST POPULAR</h3>
                    <MostPopularApps />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

here's the MostPopularApps.js page

```
const MostPopularApps = () => (
    <div>
    {console.log('printing inside most popular apps')}
        <p>MOST POPULAR APPS</p>
        <App />
    </div>
)
```

and here's the output

```
render lifecycle
printing inside most popular apps
(11)and all the arrays in response.data.list
render lifecycle
printing inside most popular apps 
{apps: Array(11)}
```

upon further reading I have discovered componentDidMount() calls every time the state changes? so is there a way to change the state without using componentDidMount()

Comment: where does this output of 'and all the arrays...' is coming from?

Comment: @Shimi I believe it comes from the `console.log(response.data.list)` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output, it seems like the render function is being called twice, which makes sense, the first time when the component mounts, and the second time when the state changes. In order to make sure you are rendering `apps` once, you can try to set a condition on the render function to only render the app when the state is populated with the apps as follows:

```
export default class HomePageComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super();
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.list)
        this.setState({apps:response.data.list})
        console.log(this.state)
    })
}

render() {
    console.log('render lifecycle')
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state?.apps?.length > 1 &&
            <BrowserRouter >
                <div className="most-popular-grid">
                    <h3 className="mostpopulartitle">MOST POPULAR</h3>
                    <MostPopularApps />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
          }
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: is there a way to set the state from a fetch call and have it run only once? I'm not sure how many apps are going to go on the homepage yet so I'm wary of coding in some conditional logic like that

Comment: Is there a flag from the response that you can use in order to know whether the `apps` had finished loading?

Comment: And you can be less specific with the condition and use `this.state?.apps?`

Comment: there is not a flag for that response. I guess I could add one. and can you explain the `this.state?.apps?`. I've never seen question marks used in js variables I think

Comment: `this.state?.apps?` is similar to `this.state && this.state.apps`, just a quick nice shortcut. Read more about Null Propagation Operator here https://ponyfoo.com/articles/null-propagation-operator

Comment: I used the code you provided above but I still get `render lifecycle` printing twice. `printing from popular apps` only shows up once.  I guess I'm still a little confused by your solution if you could explain it a little more please

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is logical that the render function will be called twice. And with the suggested solution you are making sure that although render is called twice, the apps are only being rendered once due to the added condition. With your current architecture, it is reasonable for render to be called twice - don't fight it unless you want to optimize the solution using hooks. with the suggested solution you are optimizing the actual rendering of the `apps` themselves to just once, but render will still be called twice.

Comment: yeah but isn't it bad it's rendering twice? and if it is how could I restructure it so that it only renders once?

Comment: You can try to use the fetch on a constructor instead of `componentDidMount`